# How to use virtualenvwrapper from within a Python script

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, pip, virtualenvwrapper

I have succesfully installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` on my system. It is working perfectly. For future convenience I want to create a script which installs all my favourite modules into an environment I name `pynumeric`, to be located in `~/.virtualenvs`. For this script I need to use `virtualenvwrapper` from wihtin my script. This, is unfortunately not working for me somehow. I keep on getting errors that `workon` and `mkvirtualenv` do not exist.

So basically my question boils down to: Why does `virtualenvwrapper` work in a terminal and **not** from within my Python script?

**install_pynumeric.py (EDIT)**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import subprocess as sp

# Set CPU frequency governer to performance
#sp.check_call('cpuset gov performance', shell=True)

# Check for parent directory of virtual environments
if not os.path.isdir('/home/carlos/.virtualenvs'):
    sys.exit('The parent directory for virtual environments does not exist yet. Create it before preceeding.')

# Create virtual environment pynumeric if it does not exist yet and activate
if not os.path.isdir('/home/carlos/.virtualenvs/pynumeric'):
    sp.check_call('mkvirtualenv pynumeric', shell=True)

# Activate pynumeric
sp.check_call('workon pynumeric', shell=True)

# List of Python modules to be installed
modules = ['numpy',
        'scipy',
        'sympy',
        'matplotlib',
        'pyqt4',
        'sphinx',
        'rope',
        'pyflakes',
        'ipython',
        'pylint',
        'psutil',
        'spyder',
        'pydstool'
        ]

# Install modules
for m in modules:
    cmd = 'pip install ' + m
    sp.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

# Deactivate pynumeric
sp.check_call('deactivate', shell=True)

# Set CPU frequency governer to ondemand
#sp.check_call('cpuset gov ondemand', shell=True)
```

I get the following error now:

```
/bin/sh: mkvirtualenv: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./install_pynumeric.py", line 16, in <module>
    sp.check_call('mkvirtualenv pynumeric', shell=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'mkvirtualenv pynumeric' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Doesn't work because `deactivate` is a function and not a script.

---

I've run into the same issue a while ago, and I suggest you use `subprocess` to run your commands, with the `shell` parameter set to `True`. This will use your current environment and not create an entirely new one.

Example :

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call("deactivate", shell=True)
```

Comment: No does not work. I have edited my post with your changes and the corresponding error message.

Comment: Ha, damn. `deactivate` is actually a Bash function. Well, I learned something today!

Comment: Just noticed the possible duplicate, but the answer doesn't work on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). I'm kinda interested in the solution now ;)

Comment: The solution is also not working for me.